# Symfony 3 form many-to-many

Tags: php, many-to-many, symfony-forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a form where I can place an order. My database schema looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have a form like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
$order = new Order();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($order)
    ->add('naam', TextType::class)
    ->add('email', EmailType::class)
    ->add('phoneNumber', TextType::class)
    ->add('dateTakeout', DateType::class)
    ->add('hourTakeout', DateType::class)
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Verzenden'))
    ->getForm();
```

But I'm stuck with adding the products to my form. How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

The connection of my product and category is like this:

[image]

I have a Category entity with id, name, enabled and parentCategoryId.

In my Product entity I have a category property.

I would like to show the categories and products like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you want the products appearing on the form? A drop down list maybe? Like being able to select the Product? Or are those number fields where you can enter "quantities" of products?

Comment: @AlvinBunk: I want to show ALL the products and you can give in a quantity (thats the number field in many to many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your form:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
...
->add('product_A', IntegerType::class)
->add('product_B', IntegerType::class)
->add('product_C', IntegerType::class)
->add('product_D', IntegerType::class)
```

This is an Integer, so you can simply call:

```
$prodA_amount = $form->get('product_A')->getData();
```

to get the value...

Comment: And how can I group them in category?

Comment: If it's just visual, use a `<fieldset>` tag with `<legend>` tag and then logically group them. Maybe I don't understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to group the products in the category (as you see on image). But how can I do this in my controller and show the products under each category in my view?

Comment: Let me ask, are Products A & B part of "Category A" and do you have a Entity called Category, and an "object" of "Category_A". Or something like that. I don't know what you refer to as group the products. The form itself is just visual.

Comment: I think my answer is still correct. You still want an input field where the user types in a "Integer" of the quantity they want, then you use for example `$prodA_amount = $form->get('product_A')->getData();` to get the value (qty) for Product A, and then you can store this in the Entity of Product A.

Comment: Yes, But how can I group them? There is no way now I can group them in my view

Answer (score 0):

I see this as embedding multiple forms for the Entity `OrderHasProducts`,

When initializing your form object, you will need to loop over all products (Or some of them depending on your requirements) and add them to the `Order` new instance, then let symfony do its magic regarding creating the form.

To create the embedded form :

```
$builder->add('order_has_products', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => OrderHasProduct::class
));
```

And create your form for the OrderHasProduct entity

(check the docs [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) )

and in your controller , something like the following :

```
$order = new Order();
foreach($products as $product) :
// you may wanna create your custom method here
    $order->addOrderProduct((new OrderHasProduct())
                        ->setOrder($order)
                        ->setProduct($product));
endforeach;
```